# TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined

Tags: token, mean-stack

I am facing this error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined
 - Here's [a link](https://github.com/DemigodR/MEAN_Stack/blob/master/server.js)! to my github page

I am using a firefox addon to post data and sending data in json format like: {"x-access-token": "jashiuahf"}

Here is the image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMK6Q.png) @fabio

Can anybody help me solve this please!!!

Comment: Sorry I didn't define when the problem occurs: When I try posting on localhost:8080/me the above error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the error comes from these lines

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
console.log(req.headers['x-access-token']);
var token = req.body.token || req.body.query || req.headers['x-access-token'];
........ more code ....
```

I think that `req.body.token` or `req.body.query` is not the place to look for authentication or access token, always try to look for it in the request header. The error is because `token` is not a property of `req.body`, just

```
var token = req.headers['x-access-token'] || '';
```

should work.

also check this question: [get authorization header token with node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44366993/get-authorization-header-token-with-node-js)

Comment: I tried that, but when i tried console logging it I got undefined as the response on console.log(req.headers['x-access-token']) when I posted. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Probably cause you’re not sending The token with the request, are you ? How are you doing It?

Comment: I am using a firefox addon to post data and sending data in json format like: {"x-access-token": "jashiuahf"}

Comment: Can you Edit The question and add an screenshot?

Comment: Did it work on your system? @fabio I've added the image up there

Comment: Yes, as you can see next to `content to Send` there's the `Headers paramters` option, you can sen the access token from there...

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same error while working with Node and Express..

Turns out I didn't require cookie-parser dependency at the top make sure you require and mount it

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());
```